# How can i access a folder in Total Commander using command line?

Tags: total-commander

I'm standing at E:\Desktop\ and i want to open a folder has name is New folders inside Desktop folder.
In command line, i type New folders (very simple).Then i received a message box "File not found".
Who can help me this case?
Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

You use the same syntax as if you would in a Windows Command Prompt

```
cd "New folders"
```

It eludes me why you want to do this, but anyway...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you said, i must type completely its location in command line. it's "cd E:\Desktop\New folder". It's a nightmare. It should have a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

of course you will get this error message. First you need to create a new folder with this command mkdir  then cd New-FileName  (Note- remove this <, >)

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my case, "New folder" is still exists inside Desktop folder and I want to navigate to it without type cd. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'quick search' option pressing Ctrl + s and starting to enter a folder name - New....

You can set the 'quick search' to be used by default in the command line. Go to Configuration -> Options... -> Operation -> Quick Search -> Quick Search (Current dir) and choose 'Letters - with search dialog'.